# SAPUI5 Spinner is not working in higher versions of android

Tags: android, sapui5

I have developed an application using SAPUI5. The spinner has to appear when navigating from one page to other. The spinner works fine on jelly bean android version. But fails on higher versions. Can anyone help me with this?

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('loadingIndicator').setText("Loading...");
sap.ui.getCore().byId('loadingIndicator').open();
```

Comment: You should always give a [mcve] if you expect others to help you...

Answer (score 0):

use [`sap.m.BusyDialog`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.BusyDialog.html)

```
var oBusyDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
oBusyDialog.open();// will work when DOMis already there 
oBusyDialog.close();//else it throws error and page completely fails in IE.
```

hence put it in **try catch**

```
try{
 oBusyDialog.open();
}catch(e){
 //Error handler
 console.log("Busy dialog couldn't be loaded:"+e);
}
```

[Check Preview here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.BusyIndicator/preview)

> Note: On Page refresh, DOM will not loaded before you call open() or
>   close() method, hence put it in try catch.